# How to move inside collection of nested dictionar Array JSON response using swift 2.0

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am totally new to swift and getting trouble access the array content which is inside two dictionary level

```
{
  "responsecode": "200",
  "responsemsg": "Product List",
  "total_pages_count": "35",
  "data": [
{
  "pk_productid": 403,
  "fk_userid": 59,
  "productname": "Intencity",
  "sku": "man-intencity403",
  "description": "",
  "shortdescription": "",
  "prodsaletype": 1,
  "prodprice": 325000,
  "is_approve": 1,
  "issold": false,
  "issoldprice": 0,
  "isbid": 0,
  "lastbidprice": 325000,
  "isdiscount": false,
  "isfixeddiscount": false,
  "discountamt": 0,
  "ispromocode": false,
  "isonline": false,
  "iscash": true,
  "images": [
    {
      "imagepath": "http://www.artively.com/Upload/ProdColorThumbImage/270120161509_Intensity_Fotor.jpg",
      "imgvideotype": 1
    }
  ],
... 
..
.
```

I am able to access the response code as well as the second level ie SKU, description etc but how to access *images array* here i have to access the *imagepath* and show the image in uitableview

Here is my code

```
   func parseJSONData(data: NSData) -> [ProductDetails] {
    var product_Detail = [ProductDetails]()
    do {
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        let jsonProductDetails = jsonResult?["data"] as! [AnyObject]
        print("the json response is",jsonProductDetails)

        for jsonproductDetail in jsonProductDetails{
            let productDetail = ProductDetails()

            productDetail.productAuthor = jsonproductDetail["first_name"]as! String
            productDetail.productPrice =  jsonproductDetail["prodprice"]as! Int

           product_Detail.append(productDetail)

            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray

            let jsonProductImageDetails = (jsonResult?["images"] as! [AnyObject]
            print("the json response is",jsonProductImageDetails)
          //How to access array
        }
    }
    catch {
        print (error)
    }
    return product_Detail
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `jsonResult?["images"]` should be `jsonproductDetail["images"]`

Comment: Sir you are great...Thank you

Comment: @Caleb Sir, if i want to display the images in async. way then i have to store the image url in an array and display it accordingly....Is i am going in the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

I think Caleb nailed the original problem, but wanted to add - I was trying to deal with some JSON in Swift the other day and realized that it's kind of a nightmare to unpack it.  I found a Cocoapod called "SwiftyJSON" that makes it a lot easier....

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON